# How to calculate the volume of water in a certain amount of air, given the relative humidity?

Tags: water, volume, condensation, humidity

If, according to the weather forecast, the current humidity is 90%, how can I calculate the volume of water that could be extracted from a certain volume of that air?

Comment: Steam tables are your friend (to convert from relative to absolute humidity)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a ***psychrometric chart***.

[image: psychrochart]

On the x-axis, input the value of a common air thermometer (it's the *dry bulb temperature*). Now follow a vertical line until you reach the red curve that reads *90% relative humidity*.

Follow the horizontal line to the y-axis on the right and that *humidity ratio* will be the ratio of water versus dry air (mass-wise). That is, **0.015** means that **1.015 kg** of your current air has **1.000 kg** of dry air plus **0.015 kg** of water vapor.

To turn that into volume of water per volume of air (*air* is different from *dry air*), you'll have to do a little math and unit conversion. You can use 1.2 kg/m³ as the density of dry air (at 20°C) if it helps.