# How is it possible to calculate the water content of air in liters ( from relative humidity and temperature )?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, air, humidity

My home has 150 m<sup>3</sup> air. I would like to calculate, that how much liters of water this air contains, if the temperature is 25 C° and the relative humidity is 60%. I would like to calculate it for 26 C° and 54% as well.

There is [a similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/596684/what-is-the-formula-to-calculate-the-amount-of-water-in-the-air-at-a-certain-tem), but the answer does not explain, where the $P, A, B, T$ parameters come from, and what do they mean.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this table that shows the maximum water content, it is for 100% humidity, then just adjust for the % humidity and multiply by the volume.

It's from https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/maximum-moisture-content-air-d_1403.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Iter Ator, most substances have a vapor pressure which depends on temperature.  Data for vapor pressure vs. temperature for a given substance must be acquired experimentally, and it has been found that the Antoine equation produces a very good fit to this experimental data.  The Antoine equation has 3 constants in it, namely "A", "B", and "C".  With vapor pressure being denoted by "P" and temperature being denoted by "T", the equation becomes

$Log_{10} (P) = A - \frac{B}{T+C}$

Note that "T" may be in Celsius, Fahrenheit, or an absolute temperature scale, and the constants that result from fitting the experimental data will change depending on which temperature scale is used.  In order to avoid confusion for those using this equation, the temperature scale that was used to generate the constants must be specified.